# How to download a video file from youtube?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

Bellow i have some code that completes the download process of a youtube video. It works once and then does not work a second time so i put this line of code in `[videoData retain];` which stops the thread error i was receiving. However once adding `[videoData retain];` my downloader downloads twice instead of once when downloading a second video it does not do this when downloading the first...

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        videoData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        [videoData appendData:data];

    }

    //when downloading done
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%f.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
        [videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        [videoData retain];

        [videoData release];


        NSLog(@"LOCAL VIDEO LINK %@",filePath);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Downloading complete"
                                                       message: @"Download complete. You have successfully downloaded your video from youtube"
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Go Back"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];


    }
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 0");
            // Any action can be performed here
            [movieController stop];
            [movieController.view removeFromSuperview];
            bar.hidden = YES;
            texturl.text = nil;
            hidden.hidden = YES;
            videoData = nil;




        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 1");
            // Any action can be performed here
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you keep deleting and reposting your questions over?

Comment: You might want to check out the [YouTube Terms & Conditions page](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms): *"5.1 YouTube hereby grants you permission to access and use the Service, subject to the following express conditions... C) you agree **not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Website itself, the YouTube Player, or such other means as YouTube may explicitly designate for this purpose**"* (my emphasis)

Comment: @rmaddy this is a different question to my last because i figured out that problem but i now have another